# Etherpad Lite how to change font size

Tags: etherpad

How can I change the size of the text in etherpad lite? I can't find any informations in the css-files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve this by editing [custom static files](http://etherpad.org/doc/v1.2.7/#index_custom_static_files).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own plugin to do that.

In ep.json, add a client_hook:

```json
{
  "parts": [
    {
      "name": "myPlugin",
      "client_hooks": {
        "aceEditorCSS": "ep_myPlugin/static/js/ace"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In static/js/ace.js, write only that:

```json
exports.aceEditorCSS = function(hook_name, cb) { // inner pad CSS;
    return ['ep_myPlugin/static/css/ace.css'];
}
```

and in static/css/ace.css:

```css
#innerdocbody {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

You are done !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this either with custom static files or use the ep_font_size plugin, that way the user can change their own font size.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me too, but need to restart etherpad-lite server and wipe the browser cache carefully.